# Frustrating ElementNotVisibleException error

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting the following error when I attempt to click a button:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Command duration or timeout: 10.06 seconds

I've tried the following and none worked:

1) Waiting for 10 seconds in case the page is being loaded

2) Used JS executor thus:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", By.cssSelector("#IconButton > input.IconButtonDisplay"));
```

3) Used wait until element is visible

Number 2 is actually executed but the results of the click don't eventuate i.e. new page does not open.

Number 3 times out stating button is not visible, but button is visible and can be manually clicked.

What I can tell you is that using the Selenium IDE I am able to playback and click the button no problems.

HTML of button (can't put too much here as proprietary information). Apologies for formatting:

```
<div widgetid="dijit__WidgetsInTemplateMixin_13" id="dijit__WidgetsInTemplateMixin_13" class="gridxCellWidget">
  <div class="IconButton" widgetid="IconButton" id="IconButton" data-dojo-type="ab.cd.ef.gh.IconButton" data-dojo-attach-point="rowBtn1Pt">
    <input class="IconButtonDisplay" src="/tswApp/ab/cd/ef/gh/images/edit.png" style="width: 20px;" type="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide any reproducible scenario?

Comment: Sorry Saifur, I clicked post before I'd completed updating the question! :-(

Comment: Forgot to mention, once the test fails I can also manually click the button without any issues.

Comment: Please provide the HTML of the element and possibly surrounding HTML as needed. Why are you using JavascriptExecutor and not just driver.findElement(By.cssSelector())? That error means that the element isn't visible to users. Are you sure you have the right element?

Comment: I am using JSE as driver.findElementBy is what is failing with the element not visible exception. Added some HTML.

Comment: if it works with Selenium IDE, then please export the code and post the Locator that Selenium IDE is using to find the button...

Comment: There is nothing in the HTML code which is a button. So click the element which is the button.

This is handled by the browser so of course you can do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript executor you want to pass the instance of WebElement not the By selector. So change

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",   By.cssSelector("#IconButton > input.IconButtonDisplay"));
```

to

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#IconButton > input.IconButtonDisplay"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the same issue as before i.e. it executes the script but the actual button click does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using FirefoxDriver?

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Have you tried just using this? Is this not unique enough?

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.IconButtonDisplay")).click();
```

If not, try this (it's the equivalent to what you were doing with JSE)

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#IconButton > input.IconButtonDisplay")).click();
```

Maybe it's not the INPUT that takes the click? Have you tried clicking either of the parent DIVs?

```
driver.findElement(By.id("IconButton")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dijit__WidgetsInTemplateMixin_13")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

for me this is what worked:

```
   JavascriptLibrary jsLib = new JavascriptLibrary(); 
   jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver,"triggerMouseEventAt", editButton,"click", "0,0");
```

Hope this helps others who are having the same problem.